# process an input file with "name = value " pairs using perl

Tags: regex, perl

The simulation code I use needs to read parameters from an input.txt file which looks like

```
paramA = 1,paramB = 2,
paramC = 3,paramD = 4,
```

When scanning a parameter (like paramC) in my simulation, I need to change the value of paramC every time manually. How can I do this with a perl script so that when I type

```
perl scriptname input.txt paramC 100
```

in the command line I can get a modified input file with paramC changed to 100

```
 paramA = 1,paramB = 2,
 paramC = 100,paramD = 4,
```

I can do this by creating a template file like

```
paramA = 1,paramB = 2,
paramC = <>,paramD = 4,
```

and then use perl to match the mark <> and replace it with the value I want. However is there a more direct way to match the parameter name and change its value ?

thanks.

Comment: How about `s/^paramC = \K[^ ,]+/$value/`?

Comment: Hmm, that's a neat pattern, I didn't think it'd work at first glance, but having tried it it works nicely. I might be inclined to go with `\d+` though.

Answer (score 2):

The obvious answer is to use a regular expression. Perl is quite good at those.

So you could - for example - do:

```
s/paramC = \d+/paramC = $value/g;
```

Which'll do the trick I'd have thought?

Edit: Or use TLP's pattern in the comments:

```
s/^paramC = \K[^ ,]+/$value/g;
```

or perhaps:

```
s/^paramC = \K\d+/$value/g;
```